# What is the exact difference between "called" and "so-called"?

Tags: adjectives, hyphenation, past-participles

Actually, in English to Korean dictionary, both of "called" and "so-called" have the same meaning.

In many examples of the dictionary, "so-called" is used as adjective rather than past-particle, i.e., it is placed before the noun.

On the other hand, "called" is used as past particle many times.

---

However, recently I've frequently observed that the word "so-called" is used as past-particle like "called".

---

What is exact difference between called and so-called? (Not only meaning but also usage)

The following two sentences are the example I made:

> Networks that consist of multiple mobile nodes are promising technology, so-called mobile ad hoc networks (MANETs).
>
> Networks that consist of multiple mobile nodes are promising technology, called mobile ad hoc networks (MANETs).

Comment: Please consult dictionaries to answer questions like this. (btw Study, as a verb, does not take a preposition. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is slight.  Often, but not always, *so-called* is carries an air of disapproval, suggesting the name is in some way clumsy, inept or inappropriate.

Personally, I don’t detect such a tone in your example.  Another way of signalling disapproval is the use of single inverted commas, sometimes called ‘scare’ quotes, because they say to the reader, “be careful, I am not committed to the bit between single quotes in any literal way”.  This use of single quotes has also been called *sneer quotes*, for obvious reasons.  But in my experience, there are no hard and fast rules about this.

I myself should prefer *called* to *so-called* in the context you have given.  I doubt if the author meant to hint at disapproval of the acronym for a programming feature.

Answer (score 0):

"Called" is a definition. Think of it like an equals sign.

"So-called" generally implies there's something not quite equal (e.g., "so-called leader" for someone in charge but doesn't actually lead). It can also be a common name that isn't its official name.

Comment: A mistake sometimes made is to use both 'so-called' and scare quotes, e.g. _a so-called "expert"_. That is redundant because both the 'so-called' and the double quote marks imply they are not really an expert.